# Execute COPY command on Redshift database from a Linux server outside AWS cluster

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want to load data into Redshift database from amazon S3 using 'COPY' command.But I want to execute it from a shell/perl  script present in a Linux machine present outside AWS cluster.I wanted to know if there is any Redshift  client that can be installed in the Linux machine available to help me achieve this similar to the SnowSQL client for SnowFlake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this. 
[psql- a terminal-based front end from PostgreSQL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html)

You just have to connect to your redshift cluster with the connection configuration and then you can execute any query on the cluster. 
 
PS - The file to be copied/Unload always has to be on s3.

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Can I use this tool to connect from a Linux server which is present outside the cluster?I am assuming I have psql installed in the Linux server.

Comment: Yes, you can, as long as you have necessary credentials and permissions.

Comment: Hi @Rahul Gupta, Thanks for the response.I tried it out actually it worked.Just one additional ask.There is a redshift-CLI as per the Redshift documentation.Does it allow the same functionality?

Comment: I don't think so. You will need a client because CLI is just for managing the clusters.

Comment: And if CLI is the only option you have, you can use Data Pipeline, which is usually used to automate the process.